# Symfony debug toolbar is displaying, but not working

Tags: php, debugging, symfony1

My Symfony debug toolbar (v1.3.7) is appearing correctly but clicking it generates a javascript error.

Looking through the source code, I can see that the javascript for the toolbar is not being sent back to the browser. I have another project set up on the same machine which uses Symfony v1.4 and this works fine.

This project is also set up on one of my colleages' machines and it is working fine. The project itself is also running without problems.

Any ideas what might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't correctly link the assets in your web root.

You need to copy/symlink/... **/path/to/symfony/data/web/sf** to **/path/to/project/web/sf**

Comment: I managed to fix the problem by trying different versions of Symfony. Version 1.3.7 seems to be the only one that doesn't work for me. I have reinstalled a fresh copy but that made no difference.